# Hashbytes equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, md5, hashbytes

I am moving my data from SQL Server to MySQL. The data is moving without any issues, but I am trying to come up with a way to validate the integrity of the data between SQL Server and MySQL. I am having issues with regards datatypes **VARCHAR** and **NVARCHAR**. Since these are ranging from **255 to MAX**. I am trying to do hash comparison between these datatypes but they are not matching.

For testing purpose I tried this:

```
mysql> SET @test := repeat('t',50000);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select md5(@test);
+----------------------------------+
| md5(@test)                       |
+----------------------------------+
| a9cf60d59fe2fb94a84bc106eca028be |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Trying the same in SQL Server gives something different:

```
DECLARE @Test NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), N't'), 50000);

SELECT HashBytes('MD5', CONVERT(varchar, @Test));

0x3C48C287BC783516AC89297848A104FE

select LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', CONVERT(varchar, @Test)), 2));

3c48c287bc783516ac89297848a104fe

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', @Test),2);

40752EB301B41EEAEB309348CE9711D6
```

As you can see none of the output in SQL Server is not matching with MySQL. Hence, looking for some guidance here as to how can I do this data comparison.

Comment: Can't you try with SHA?

Comment: @gotqn I did try with that but same outcome. The hash on SQL Server is different than MySQL

Comment: @gotqn Tested, but the result of Binary Checksum is not hash but instead numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One page as a unit of data storage for sql server database file is only `8KB` and the limit for `varchar` `LEN` is `8000`, so following your test example, you won't be able to get the hex result of `50000` characters per page. Instead, it is the result of your `@Test` example that is calculated on a string length of 8000 characters.

Comment: As per my knowledge, this limitation is no longer there starting SQL Server 2016.